# Possible to exclude something within a capture group?

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a telephone number:

```
310-5984
```

I want to capture all numbers in the phone number, that is, `3105984`. I can do this with two capturing groups:

```
>>> re.match(r'(?P<num_1>\d+)-(?P<num_2>\d+)', '310-5984').groupdict()
{'num_1': '310', 'num_2': '5984'}
```

Is it possible to get the full number with one capturing group? I tried doing something like:

```
>>> re.match(r'(?P<num>(?P<num_1>\d+)(?:-)(?P<num_2>\d+))', '310-5984').groupdict()
{'num': '310-5984', 'num_1': '310', 'num_2': '5984'}
```

But it was also consuming the separator. How can I 'consume' the separator but not capture it in a group? Or is that impossible with regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `re.sub` with a callback function, e.g.

```
def callback(m):
    return m.group(1) + m.group(2)

phone = "310-5984"
number = re.sub('\\b(\d+)-(\d+)\\b', callback, phone)
print(number)
```

This prints:

```
3105984
```

The callback function lets you do an additional step involving all the capture groups obtained from the call to `re.sub`.  In this case, we are just combining them.

Comment: nice! I just put it in a lambda function and it works great: `re.sub('(\d+)-(\d+)', lambda match: match.group(1) + match.group(2), '310-5984')`

Comment: That's a very nice one-liner.  I might use that myself later on.

Comment: by the way -- is the above regex group-concatention not possible to do without using a substitution? i.e., is it possible to capture `3105984` with a pure regex?

Comment: No, not in a single capture group.  You either need to use a callback (my answer), or just match `310-5984` and then strip the dash afterwards yourself.